Entropy of random walk on a chessboard queen less than rook + bishop
I am looking at Cover's textbook on information theory and computed the entropies for random walks of chess pieces on an 8x8 board as follows:
Rook: can move to 14 squares wherever it is $\to H(Rook) = log_2(14) \approx 3.8$
Bishop: can access the following number of squares, depending on where it is:
[ 7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7]
[ 7,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  7]
[ 7,  9, 11, 11, 11, 11,  9,  7]
[ 7,  9, 11, 13, 13, 11,  9,  7]
[ 7,  9, 11, 13, 13, 11,  9,  7]
[ 7,  9, 11, 11, 11, 11,  9,  7]
[ 7,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  7]
[ 7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7]

So, I get $(28/64)*log_27 + (20/64)*log_29 + (12/64)log_211 + (4/64)log_213 \approx 3.1$
Queen: Behaves like a Rook + Bishop
So, I get $(28/64)*log_2(14+7) + (20/64)*log_2(14+9) + (12/64)log_2(14+11) + (4/64)log_2(14+13) \approx 4.5$
While I believe my calculations are correct and I can see that $log(a) + log(b) > log(a+b)$, my intuition says that the uncertainty in the Queen's movement should be $\geq$ the uncertainties of Rook + Bishop, especially when accounting for the fact that a single bishop can only be on one color.
Where is my mistake?

Sum of the entropies would be what you get if you independently move a bishop and a rook - i.e., if you started with two pieces in one spot, and moved one like a bishop, and another like a rook. It is not unreasonable that this dominates the entropy from moving a single piece as a queen.

Also, btw, if you're computing the entropy rate of the uniform random walk according to these pieces, then your bishop and queen calculations are off: the entropy rate is a conditional entropy of $X_1|X_0$ assuming $X_0$ is drawn from the stationary distribution. For the uniform random walk, the stationary distribution of each state is proportional to the degree of the state, not uniform as in your calculation.

Ok, that makes sense. thanks! If you put this as an answer I will accept.
